# StringOutofBoundsException

Tags: java, exception

when I put in the while loop for n, an out of bounds exception appears, if I take it out it's perfect. I'm to add the data to an array later on, but it's producing an error for ....

```
String day = date.substring(0, spacePos);
```

The exception is as follows:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:21)

```
Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);              // I/O Stream
    String months[] = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"};   // Months to Compare
    int n = userInputScanner.nextInt();

    while(n != 0)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter Data: ");
        String date = userInputScanner.nextLine();                  // Input and Store Data
        String output;                                              // Program Output

        int spacePos = date.indexOf(" ");                           // Data before first space
        int lastSpacePos = date.lastIndexOf(" ");                   // Data after last space

        String day = date.substring(0, spacePos);                   // First String
        String month = date .substring(spacePos + 1, lastSpacePos); // Middle String
        String year = date.substring(lastSpacePos + 1);             // Last String

        output = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;                    // Output new values
        System.out.print(output);   
    }
```

Could anyone help me on this error please? If you need more data, please ask.

Comment: You have all the data you need to solve this yourself. Read the javadoc for [`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) and look closely at line 21 in your code and figure out how this line might cause said exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `int n = userInputScanner.nextInt();` you leave a trailing new-line that is immediately consumed by the next `nextLine()` call. You get an empty line and thus your `String` calls are invalid.

```
int n = userInputScanner.nextInt();
while(n != 0)
{
    System.out.print("Enter Data: ");
    String date = userInputScanner.nextLine();
    if (date.length() == 0) continue; // <-- retry.
```

Or, something like

```
int n = userInputScanner.nextInt();
userInputScanner.nextLine(); // <-- consume trailing newline.
while(n != 0)
{
    System.out.print("Enter Data: ");
    String date = userInputScanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the second one worked like a charm, but I will incorporate the first also, for exception handling.